# Pylons redirect gives: AttributeError: 'HTTPFound' object has no attribute 'exception'

Tags: python, pylons

(This question is documenting my research for a bug, to save others the time it took me to resolve.)

I have a web-page built on the Pylons 1.0.1 framework.

The developers recommend an upgrade path of migrating to Pyramids, their new product. No further work will be done on Pylons 1.0.1.

However, I do not need any further features - the web-site is in maintenance, so I have not upgraded the framework.

Recently, after deploying some other changes to the server, the web-site stopped working, despite no changes to my code. In particular, a call to redirect gave the error:

> AttributeError: 'HTTPFound' object has no attribute 'exception'

Answer (score 5):

Pylons relies on WebOb. In the dependencies, it demands that WebOb >= 1.3.1 be installed.

In WebOb 1.3.1, an attribute 'exception' was provided. This attribute is used by Pylons in the redirect code.

This attribute has been deprecated for some time, and was initially planned for removal in 1.3.

On May 14, 2014, WebOb 1.4 was released. Although it is not included in the release notes, one of the changes was to [remove the exception attribute](https://github.com/Pylons/webob/commit/7153f9a2f31c7bf7794e846546a42ec0fe617477).

Therefore, if you install Pylons 1.0.1 and let it select all of its dependencies, it will include a version of WebOb which it is no longer compatible with.

This explains the problem.

(The solution is less clear: downgrading WebObs? Waiting for a possibly-never-existing Pylons 1.0.2? Migrating to Pyramid?)

Comment: The solution I adopted: Before installing Pylons, I install a deliberately old version of WebOb: i.e. `webob<1.4`

Comment: Apparently this is going to be fixed in Pylons 1.0.2. I don't have a timeline for that though.

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded to the latest versions of :
https://github.com/Pylons/pylons
and
https://github.com/Pylons/webob
and the problem went away!

Here are my steps :

```
git clone git@github.com:Pylons/webob.git
cd webob/ & python setup.py install --user
git clone git@github.com:Pylons/pylons.git
cd pylons/ & python setup.py install --user
```

The exact versions I am on:

pylons:

```
pylons$ git log -1 --decorate=full
commit 7e8bac74046ba1ae1509c844fa5cd878490a3413 (HEAD, refs/remotes/origin/master, refs/remotes/origin/HEAD, refs/heads/master)
Date:   Tue Jul 7 18:05:23 2015 -0700
```

webob:

```
webob$ git log -1 --decorate=full
commit 565fe4420c147623c4a8f1077d6deab7ba732040 (HEAD, refs/remotes/origin/master, refs/remotes/origin/HEAD, refs/heads/master)
Date:   Sat Jun 27 22:03:39 2015 -0600
```

See also my install steps for zookeepr where I found this problem :

https://github.com/flosokaks/zookeepr/commit/70766f190d58c04fec625be82ec56b7c6d405fb7#diff-7d442b7eb49f5fc377f51e74b291cfc1R18

Comment: What versions did you install?

Comment: @Oddthinking as updated in the description, on master latest branch for both.